# Что значит выражение "Диво ули ляду" в подблюдных песнях?

Tags: значение-слов, устаревшие-слова

Во многих подблюдных песнях встречается выражение "Диво ули ляду".

> Ползет ёжик По завалинке, Тащит казну На мочалинке. Диво ули ляду!
>
> Куют кузнецы, Золотые венцы Диво ули ляду!

Может кто-нибудь объяснить, что это значит?

Answer (score 1):

В русских подблюдных песнях - традиции язычества. Рефрен «Диво ули ладо!» - прославление божества. Слово «див» родственно обозначениям бога в других индоевропейских языках, в русском встречается  очень редко и в модификации «диво».

Припевы «Диво!», «Слава, ладо мое!», «Ладу, ладу!» употребляются в песнях, предвещающих богатство и счастье, в припеве белорусских бородных жнивных песен «Дзіва, дзіва мне, маёй барадзе». Ладо - божество, ведающее любовью в календарной и свадебной обрядности. У слова «лад» значение «семейный порядок», «соединение». В этом плане интересны украинские свадебные песни – «ладканки», сопровождающиеся хлопаньем в ладони, припевы «Ладу, ладу!», «Слава! Ой ладо мое!», «Ой, ладу!», «Млада!» в подблюдных песнях, предвещающих свадьбу, «Диво ули ляду!» – вечное девичество, а также припевы «Ой, дид ладо» или «Адным ладам» в хороводной песне «А мы просо сеяли», где наблюдается соединение аграрных и брачных мотивов.

В святочных гаданиях используют подблюдные песни с этим же рефреном, там тоже славят божество, просят лучшей доли. "Ули", видимо, модификация Ильи-пророка. Разновидностью подблюдных песен были, по народной терминологии, йлии: каждая песня начиналась со специального запева, обращенного к Илье-пророку, которого народ соединил с древним небесным божеством — громовником (возможно, Перуном):

Как сегодня у нас страшные вечера, Илия!

Страшные вечера да васильевские, Илия!

Поют песни первоначальные, Илия!

Илия - Улия - ули - областнические модификации (север - юг). Получается, смысл рефрена - примирить бога грома и бога лада, прославление их обоих, это ведь "страшные"вечера, когда разгул нечисти, а эти божества должны нечисть разогнать, чтобы правила Любовь.